# How to remove harden screws and try preserve the two metals that the screw bind together

Tags: screws

**The situation**

There is a screw that is binding two metals together. The screw were being fast drill in order to remove the binding. Due to the fast drill, the screw is now harden. So, how to satisfy the following requirements

1. Remove the harden screws or destroy it completely or destroy the binding.
2. Preserve the two metals as much as possible

**Illustration**

[image]

Comment: Screws are already pretty hard.  However if you cut too slow, or let the bit get hot, you will indeed work-harden the hole.  When cutting at the right feed and speed, you get nice steady chips out of the hole and the drill doesn't get hot.  On the upside you have a hole punched and centered, I would just keep drilling with quality drills.

Answer (score 3):

There is a product called an 'Ezy-out' (or some variation) and other brands of similar products which are basically a reverse thread, tapered, coarse pitch tap or drill-bit. You can use these by hand or in a drill - **in reverse**-, once it bites into the screw it will begin driving itself in further or unscrewing the stuck screw.

What size and material is the stuck screw?

Liverally coating the screw in a penetrating lubricant like WD-40, applying heat to the screw to make it expand or tapping it with a hammer while trying to remove it will all help to some dregree.

[image: Easy-out set]